# Font size in vis.gam

Tags: r, plot, label, font-size, gam

I have a GAM plot which was produced by vis.gam (mgvc package) and I´m trying to change font size, labels position and to set minor ticks (not essential but desirable) generated by ticktype="detailed".

I found no option for this neither in the documentation of vis.gam nor in literature on GAM plots.

Is there any way to do it?.

Thanks for any help or hints.

Best,

Juan Carlos

Comment: You can use the normal base R plotting parameters to change the size: try `cex.lab`, and `cex.axis`. You can move the labels position away from the ticks by specifying the relevant labels..`xlab="\nXX"`. I think minor tick marks will involve a bit more work

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pvisgram code of 'labcex = ...' to increase the font size of the contour labels.

See [this page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/itsadug/versions/2.3/topics/pvisgam) for more help.